# Salt - What's the difference between Rejected and Denied?

Tags: keys, saltstack

So I have the salt master running on a server in my infrastructure and a few keys sitting there either accepted or unaccepted or... Either rejected or denied. My question is:

What's the difference between rejected or denied keys?:

```
Denied Keys:
server1
...
Rejected Keys:
server2
```

Just to let you know, I've done some searching around, and I haven't found anything about what these mean. I keep coming up with results that have to do with completely different stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Rejected** means a minion is rejected by salt-key command in salt-master.

A key is **Denied** when a minion is trying to connect the master with a different key than the previous accepted (tends to happen with two minions with the same name, one is accepted, the other tends to be denied)